# Rails launch path in manifest Firefox OS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, web-applications, firefox-os, marketplace

I want upload my webside in Firefox Market.. But I must have manifest.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest

I don't know how get launch path.. Because it is mvc.. And i don't have any 
static page  :/

I want start with resources :talks, only: [:index].. What is main URL?
Tnx for explain

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but aren't those apps supposed to be HTML/CSS/JS only, and can communicate with your backend via http?

Comment: Yes (probably), but I want to test in localhost.. I create zip and test in simulator OS.. I realy don't know what write in launch_path :/

Comment: Your application root_url probably? Which is `http:/localhost:3000/`?

Comment: Url must begin from „/”: „localhost:3000”

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. URL without a host is not URL it's a path. In rails usually app entry point is root path which is /

Comment: I do this.. I create file manifest_ctroller.rb and write in:
class ManifestController < ApplicationController
  def index
    send_file Rails.root.join('app/assets/manifest.webapp'), type: 'application/x-web-app-manifest+json'
  end
end

Also i create manifest.webapp in assets. 
"launch_path":"/"

Answer (score 0):

If you create your app using nginx just add this code into `/etc/nginx/mime.types`

```
types {
  text/html   html htm shtml;
  text/css    css;
  text/xml    xml;
  application/x-web-app-manifest+json   webapp;
}
```

Also for reference you should read [the MDN docs on how to serve manifests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest#Serving_manifests).